# Tултип с tooltipster плагин на карте изображения с panzoom

Tags: jquery

Есть простая карта изображения с тултипом при клике на `area` и возможностью увеличения\уменьшения этой карты:

```js
var $section = $('.plan');

$('.panzoom').panzoom({
  $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
  $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
  $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
  $reset: $section.find(".reset"),
  startTransform: 'scale(1)',
  increment: 0.1,
  minScale: 1,
  contain: 'invert',
  maxScale: 5,
  focal: {
    clientX: 0, 
    clientY: 0
  },
  onEnd: function(){
    X();
  }
}).panzoom('zoom', true);

$('map area').each(function(i,e){
      // console.log( $(e).data('status') );

  var data = $(e).data('maphilight') || {};
  data.fillColor = 'db2205';

  switch( $(e).data('status') ){               

    case 'sales':
      data.fillColor = 'db2205';
      data.strokeColor = 'db2205';
      data.fillOpacity = 0.5;
      break;

    case 'free':
      data.fillColor = '98c13c';
      data.strokeColor = '98c13c';
      data.fillOpacity = 0;
      break;
  }

  $(e).data('maphilight', data);

});



var resizeEvt;

$(document).on('ready.usemaps', function(){

  $('#image-map').maphilight({alwaysOn: true});
  $('map').imageMapResize();
});

$(window).on('resize.usemaps', function(){
  clearTimeout(resizeEvt);
  resizeEvt = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#image-map').maphilight({alwaysOn: true});
  });
});


$('map').imageMapResize();
$('#image-map').maphilight({alwaysOn: true});

$(window).on('resize', function () {
  clearTimeout(resizeEvt);
  resizeEvt = setTimeout(function () {

    $('#image-map').maphilight({alwaysOn: true});
  });
});




function X(){

  $('.plan-modal').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'click',
    maxWidth: 280,
    functionInit: function(instance, helper){

      var $origin =$(helper.origin),
          planTitle = $origin.attr('alt'),
          status = $origin.attr('data-status');             

      var content;

      

      if(status === 'free') {

        content = $('<div class="plan-b">' +
                    '<h5 class="plan-b__top">'+planTitle+'</h5>'+
                    '</div>');

      }

     

      instance.content(content);


    },
    fnctionReady: function(instance, helper){   

    },
    interactive: true,

  });

}

X();
```

```css
.panzoom-wrap {
  width: 480px;
  border:orangered;
}

.panzoom-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tooltipster@4.2.6/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tooltipster@4.2.6/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.js"></script>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.panzoom/3.2.2/jquery.panzoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maphilight/1.4.0/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/image-map-resizer/1.0.7/js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container plan">
   <!--  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533629663071-038eb2b96fcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=678eb638dc03df4a34fc1f481983698f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="">
     -->
    <div class="panzoom-wrap">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="panzoom">
    
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533629663071-038eb2b96fcf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;s=678eb638dc03df4a34fc1f481983698f&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1950&amp;q=80" usemap="#image-map" id="image-map" class="plan _map" width="480">

          <map name="image-map">
              <area 
                    href="#plan"
                    id="plan-1" 
                    target="" 
                    alt="1" 
                    title="1" 
                    href="1" 
                    coords="248,762,117" 
                    data-status="free"
                    class="plan-modal"
                    shape="circle">
            
              <area 
                    href="#plan"
                    id="plan-2" 
                    target="" 
                    alt="2" 
                    title="2" 
                    href="2" 
                    coords="967,818,128" 
                    data-status="free"
                    class="plan-modal"
                    shape="circle">
            
              <area 
                    href="#plan"
                    id="plan-3" 
                    target="" 
                    alt="3" 
                    title="3" 
                    href="3" 
                    coords="1547,698,53" 
                    data-status="free"
                    class="plan-modal"
                    shape="circle">
            
          </map>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="buttons genplan-buttons">
        <button class="zoom-in">+</button>
        <button class="zoom-out">-</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Использую [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) плагин для тултипа.
[panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom) для зумирования карты изображения.

При начальном положении все работает отлично, но при увеличении (клик на <kbd>+</kbd>) `tooltipster` открывается не рядом с объектом (`area`).

**Вопрос:** Как одновременно использовать `panzoom` и `tooltip` вместе, чтобы при увеличении\уменьшении картинки `tooltip` принимал правильное положение рядом с соответствующим `area` ?

Answer (score 1):

При одном из увеличений пока работает не совсем верно (
Попробуйте добавить вот эту функцию в tooltipster:

```
functionPosition: function(instance, helper, position) {

var matrix = $(".panzoom").panzoom('getMatrix');
    console.log(matrix);
    var elem = document.getElementById(helper.origin.id);
    var elemCoords = document.getElementById(helper.origin.id).coords.split(",");
    console.log(elemCoords);
    var panZoomElemRect = document.getElementById("panzoom").getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(panZoomElemRect);


    var tmpX = parseFloat(elemCoords[0])*parseFloat(matrix[0]);
    var tmpY = parseFloat(elemCoords[1])*parseFloat(matrix[0]);
    var tmpRad = parseFloat(elemCoords[2])*parseFloat(matrix[0]);
    console.log([tmpX, tmpY, tmpRad]);
    position.coord.left = tmpX - 20 + panZoomElemRect.x;
    position.coord.top = tmpY - 60/parseFloat(matrix[0]) - tmpRad + panZoomElemRect.y;
    if(position.coord.left < 150 && position.coord.left > 150-tmpRad){
        position.coord.left = 160;
    }
    if (position.coord.left > 150+480 && position.coord.left < 150+480+tmpRad){
        position.coord.left = 150+480 - 20;
    }
    if (position.coord.top < 0 && position.coord.top > -tmpRad){
        position.coord.top = 0;
    }
    if (position.coord.top > 320 && position.coord.top < 320 + tmpRad){
        position.coord.top = 320-60/parseFloat(matrix[0]) - tmpRad;
    }

    console.log(position.coord);
        return position;
},
```

В ней есть немного хардкода: `tmp - 20` и `tmpY - 50` - это просто размеры для tooltip, их надо просто расчитать и значение позиции и размера для panzoom div

Я постараюсь сделать более универсально, но хотя бы это может помочь в решении проблемы.